# Votes ending up at the wrong answer

Tags: bug, voting

For question with more than one answer with the same number of votes, it can happen that the vote for an answer ends up at the wrong answer. I think this happens if a partial update or reload changes the order of the answers for some reason.

I was hit by this more than once, and I start to find it really annoying. Because I can only change my vote if the answer has been edited, there is no obvious workaround for this bug. (I see this behavior with Safari Version 5.1.7 (6534.57.2), but I'm not sure whether this is the only browser affected.)

Comment: It happens to me as well, especially when working from my cell phone. I suspect this is an issue of latency with the MathJax! which makes the loading in coarse parts and it effectively renders the page almost useless until the loading is complete. This is particularly annoying with long pages with lots of long answers.

Comment: @Asaf It happens not only with votes, e.g. today when I attempted to temporarily delete my answer, I ended up deleting a different answer. Like Asaf, I think it is some sort of timing issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can always rescind a vote within 5 minutes of casting it. The "edit" rule only applies to votes cast more than 5 minutes ago. The system was designed to have a mechanism to amend mis-clickings and whatnots.

Comment: The correct votes have been cast more than 5 minutes ago, but when the reordering happens it is too late to cancel the votes. Perhaps this would be just a display problem, and the real problem only happens because I tend to give the original answer my upvote again (which then ends up at the wrong answer)? In any case, this is a real bug that I encountered more than once, and I haven't yet found a workaround for it.

Answer (score 1):

Some variant of this bug is still present. I downvoted this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/368216/12490) and explained in a comment why I downvoted it ("debate, arguments and extended discussion"), but now found out that the downvote actually ended up at the answer of Igor Ultra. Maybe Igor's answer isn't great, but it had already collected enough downvotes, so I'm not really happy that my downvote ended up there.

The only partial update that has happened here was the message "a new answer is there...", which was the answer which I tried to downvote. I'm actually not sure how I should report such bugs, but as this report already existed I decided to just append it here,

Comment: It happens to me frequently when using the mobile site, especially when I try to see a vote count.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 The vote count might indeed be (part of) the trigger. I have definitively used it in the case described in this answer.